# Image and preimage compositions of sets versus elements

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $A$ be a set, and $a$ be an element of $A$. I learned that following equalities are true:

1) $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$.

2) $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

My question is:

Why pre-image and image can cancel out for a single element, but for sets, it needs additional requirement.

Comment: I believe that both statements require $f$ to be injective. Consider $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{1\}.$ Then $f^{-1}(f(0))=\{0,1\}\neq\{0\}.$

Comment: @RideTheWavelet you are wrong. Consider $f:\{1,2,3\} \to \{1,2\}$ given by $f(1)=1,f(2)=1,f(3)=2$ and $a=2$. Then $f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$, so $f$ is not required to be injective.

Comment: @mathworker21 I must insist, actually. The statement must hold for *any* value of $a$, since no special conditions on $a$ have been assumed. Also, $f^{-1}(f(2))$ in your example is $\{1,2\}.$ I agree that the statement holds for the choice of $a=3$ in your example, however.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet yes sorry, I meant $a=3$. I still disagree with you actually since $a$ is fixed from the beginning. I don't think it needs to hold for all $a$. But if you still disagree, I can't say anything else.

Comment: The first inequality above is clearly incorrect whenever more than one element maps to $a$.

Comment: @RideTheWavelet good example, the first equality is indeed wrong, if it is true, it should hold for all functions. the example is a good counter example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is wrong.

Take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=x^2$.

Then $ f^{-1}(f(\{-1\}))=\{-1,1\} \neq \{-1\}$

For the first equality to be always true we must have that $f$ is injective.

Let $f:X \to Y$  injective and $a \in X$

Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(\{a\}))$

Then $y=f(x) \in f(\{a\}) \subseteq f(X)$ thus exists $x \in \{a\}$ such that $y=f(x)=f(a) \Rightarrow x=a$

because $f$ is injective,therefore $x \in \{a\}$

For the  other inclusion $a \{a\} \Rightarrow f(a) \in f(\{a\}) \Rightarrow a \in  f^{-1}(f(\{a\}))$.

Thus $\{a\}= f^{-1}(f(\{a\}))$

So for both statements to be true $f$ must be injective.